# create-react-app command failing at the very end, with errno -4058

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I've been following a video course for full stack web development, and have gotten to the react part. The video course says that the create-react-app npm package can be used to readily and easily do an initial setup of a react app file hierarchy with all dependencies.

The method discussed in the course is to install the craete-react-app package globally using `npm install -g create-react app`, which I did. Then I should be creating the react app by using `create-react-app my-project-name`. When I launch this command, i get an output like this: [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ua5p.png). In text:

> Creating a new React app in E:\University\Learning material\Web
> Development\Udemy - The Complete Web Developer in 2021 Zero to Mastery
> 2021-4\19. React.js, React Hooks, Redux (Hooks and Redux videos moved
> to end of course!)\exercise 1\robofriends.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe npm ERR! path E:\University\Learning
> material\Web Development\Udemy - The Complete Web Developer in 2021
> Zero to Mastery 2021-4\19. React.js, React Hooks, Redux (Hooks and
> Redux videos moved to end of course!)\exercise
> 1\robofriends\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js npm ERR!
> errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Amin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-02T16_25_06_903Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
> error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting robofriends/ from
> E:\University\Learning material\Web Development\Udemy - The Complete
> Web Developer in 2021 Zero to Mastery 2021-4\19. React.js, React
> Hooks, Redux (Hooks and Redux videos moved to end of course!)\exercise
> 1 Done.

The log file mentioned in the error has no extra information as far as I can see, only the same error message exactly replicated in a log file along with the preceding installation steps. Just to be sure, I've made 3 pastebins to contain the gigantic log file here: [Part 1](https://pastebin.com/7Xh6tEqv) [Part 2](https://pastebin.com/Xw8nWWsh) [Part 3](https://pastebin.com/dj44PtVy)

Methods I've tried to resolve the issue (And a combination of some) :

1. The good old restart your computer!
2. Clearing the npm cache by using`npm cache clear -f`
3. Uninstalling create-react app, and reinstalling
4. Uninstalling create-react-app and using `npx create-react-app robofriends` to first install the package and then create the app folder right after
5. Opening my command line in administrator mode

Any help or guidance on the issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Also, it might help to mention that I am using Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: try to run cmd with administrator permission

Comment: @JustRaman Thank you for your comment, I already tried that. Apparently the problem was in my path. Changed the path and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with your path (special characters etc.). If I recreate your exact path on my drive, I fail to create a react-app as well. However, if you change your directory to another one and try again it should work!

Comment: Thank you so much! This immediately solved my issue.

Comment: I suspect this a path length problem.  The user is creating their project in a directory of length 218, which isn't far off the 260-character Windows path length limit.